# How can i withdraw function open_restaurant()?

Tags: python, function, class

I need to withdraw function in class. I tried to type name of function, but get mistake: `NameError: name 'open_restaurant' is not defined`

```
class Restaurant():
   """описание ресторана"""

def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
    """Инициализирует атрибуты restaurant_name и cuisine_type."""
    self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
    self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type

def describe_restaurant(self):
    print(self.restaurant_name.title())
    print(self.cuisine_type.title())

def open_restaurant():
    print("Restaurant is open now!")

class Restaurant():
restaurant = Restaurant("Amarcord", "Italian")
print("Today I will eat in " + restaurant.restaurant_name + ".")
print(restaurant.restaurant_name + " is an " + restaurant.cuisine_type + ".")
open_restaurant()

print("\nToday I will eat in " + restaurant.restaurant_name + ", it" + " is an " 
+ restaurant.cuisine_type + ".")
```

Comment: What does it mean to withdraw a function? You want to delete it?

Comment: Show the traceback

Comment: Check your identation. Python is a whitespace-sensitive language, it seems your identation may be hiding your own bug from you. And the indentation you posted here is incorrect.

Comment: i want to print it

Comment: If `open_restaurant` is defined within the class body, it won't be visible outside the class. However, `__init__` should be, and to signal an empty class you need `pass`. There's a lot of issues with this code, but it's difficult to say what unless you fix your indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is confusing to me. Why are you redefining `Restaurant`? This should work:

```
class Restaurant:
   """описание ресторана"""

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        """Инициализирует атрибуты restaurant_name и cuisine_type."""
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(self.restaurant_name.title())
        print(self.cuisine_type.title())

    def open_restaurant(self):
        print("Restaurant is open now!")
```

We've defined the class. Let's instantiate it:

```
r = Restaurant('x', 'y')
```

Now let's call the defined method:

```
r.open_restaurant()  # Restaurant is open now!
```

Conversely, if you want to call `open_restaurant()` without instantiating the class, you can define a `@staticmethod`:

```
class Restaurant:
   """описание ресторана"""

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        """Инициализирует атрибуты restaurant_name и cuisine_type."""
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(self.restaurant_name.title())
        print(self.cuisine_type.title())

    @staticmethod
    def open_restaurant():
        print("Restaurant is open now!")
```

And then you can just call it:

```
open_restaurant()  # Restaurant is open now!
```

Comment: Won't work. `open_restaurant` is not a staticmethod, nor does it take `self` as a parameter. Considering there's already numerous issues with the OP's code, I doubt `open_restaurant` is intentionally a method.

Comment: The indentation makes it hard to understand what he wants

Comment: Right. So you should likely refrain from providing an answer until you know what they actually want.

Comment: I added an answer for both scenarios